# When I receive a phone call now, my MacBooks always open up FaceTime and do not allow me to take the call!

Tags: macos, iphone, facetime, call, wifi-calling

This started happening a few weeks ago. I just want the old functionality back again, it looks like this: 
[image]

Now, when I receive a call, FaceTime.app starts, my camera's green led comes on (due to FaceTime's preview) and I cannot even accept the call.

It seems possible that turning on WiFi calling on my Mac caused this change in behavior.

I would really like to understand what went wrong here.

Comment: Further information: I am able to (when in range) switch my phone's audio output to my Mac using the speakerphone button (I can also choose my bluetooth headsets and Speakerphone from this menu). But I cannot TAKE a call purely from the mac (leaving phone in pocket). Mega fail.

Answer (score 1):

I think what's going on is that with my 2017 Touchbar MBP the only way to take the call is to use the touchbar. This worked for me today.

Next time I will see what happens with the Macbook, which has no touchbar.